# Copy (CRTL+C) fails recurrently in first time it is used

Tags: shortcuts, clipboard, copy, paste

I have a weird problem I don't know how to solve or even to debug.

I copy (in general, no specific application) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

I would say that 70% of the times I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the copy fails and, when I paste with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, I'll paste the content that was already copied on the clipboard.

If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> like three or four times, the content will be copied but, on the first time, it will almost certainly fail.

Can somebody, please, give me any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Post specific system specs including the specific version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Can you try just **selecting text and middle-clicking** instead of the ctrl-c-ctrl-v shenanigans

Answer (score 1):

I found out this was related to the focus policy.

Since I had mouse focus policy configured, sometimes <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> would not copy since the window I was trying to copy from did not have focus.

I changed the focus policy to follow click instead of mouse, and the problem seems to be solved.